# Intern tutorial functional test exception

Tags: intern

I am struggling to run functional tests on Intern tutorial. I started on Intern using Intern tutorial at https://github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial. Unit tests were fine. But when I run functional tests using following command.

```
SAUCE_USERNAME=<MyUserName> SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY=<MyPassword> ./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern
```

I get this;

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
Ready
Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>
Error: [POST http://(redacted)@localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at exports._errnoException  <util.js:746:11>
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]  <net.js:1000:19>

TOTAL: tested 0 platforms, 0/0 tests failed; fatal error occurred
```

I followed exactly what is said in tutorial. And I am using latest Intern version 2.2. Please help.

Comment: It looks like the server is listening on port 9000 but the app is trying to connect on port 4444.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I try that.

Comment: This is normal. When Intern runs functional tests, two servers are involved: one is Intern's own proxy server, which serves test files. The other is a WebDriver server, which Intern communicates with to control browsers. By default, Intern's test server listens on port 9000, while the WebDriver server listens on port 4444.

Answer (score 0):

Node 0.12 changed how its file watcher works and [broke the Sauce Labs tunnel](https://github.com/theintern/digdug/commit/8ba5dae00c3d2e57fa5d6df08e72a6f9e826f6b1). To address this problem, use Node 0.10, don’t use Sauce Labs, apply the change in that commit locally, or wait for Intern 3 release which will include the fix.

Comment: Thanks. C Snover. Changing ports is not successful so far. I now try downloading Node 0.10. And try with that.

Comment: Hello C Snover. I installed older version of Node which ( .10.36 and .10.38) I am getting this 
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
**
A newer version of Sauce Connect (build 1674) is available!
Download it here:
https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3.8-osx.zip
**
Started scproxy on port 55786.
Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
Finished! Deleting tunnel.
Error: Not authorized
Error: Not authorized
  at reject  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:371:17>
  continues in next comment

Comment: at readStartupMessage  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:382:14>
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:457:12>
  at Array.some  <native>
  at Socket.<anonymous>  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/digdug/SauceLabsTunnel.js:451:21>
  at Socket.emit  <events.js:117:20>
  at Socket.<anonymous>  <_stream_readable.js:765:14>
  at Socket.emit  <events.js:92:17>
  at emitReadable_  <_stream_readable.js:427:10>
  at emitReadable  <_stream_readable.js:423:5>